How can I insert product details in ascending order based on the Product ID in an Azure Logic App? The current implementation is random
The person is struggling to sort and insert product details in ascending order based on the Product Id in an HTML table using an Azure Logic App. They have tried using actions like Parse JSON, Foreach, Append to Array, and Append to String Variables, but the product values are being inserted randomly. They are seeking advice on what additional actions they should include to achieve the desired outcome.
The person used actions like Parse JSON, Foreach, Append to Array, Append to String Variables, and Compose actions.

More details required. Is the function returning a JSON object? Or HTML? What programming language is used in the function and application?

I am retrieving data from a SQL Server, which is in the form of JSON. I am using actions like Initialize Variable, Parse JSON, Foreach, Append to Array, Append to String Variables, and Compose to convert the JSON into a string. Then, I am creating an HTML table using the converted data.

@ChinnaSwamula Is it feasible for you to add `ORDER BY ProductId ASC' at the end of your SQL query in the function? Or update the stored procedure in SQL if you're using a stored proc? SQL is very efficient at ordering things. If not, I'll post some code, but this would be the ideal solution. Also can you confirm what the rendering application is? Is it C#, Javascript, Power Automate etc.

I am using the ORDER BY ProductId ASC clause at the end of my SQL query. When I convert the JSON into a string, it works fine and I get the data in ascending order. However, when I try to insert the converted data into an HTML table, the values are being inserted randomly.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I've edited my answer since you're using a Logic App, not Power Automate.
To retain the order of the JSON objects based on the OrderId when constructing an HTML table in an Azure Logic App, you can sort the JSON array based on the OrderId before iterating through it to build the table.

Sort the JSON Array: Use the Sort array action to sort the JSON array based on the OrderId. Set the sorting order to Ascending.

Initialize HTML Table: Start by initializing an HTML table structure in a variable or directly in the action where you are building the table.

Iterate Through Sorted Array: Use a For each loop to iterate through the sorted JSON array.

Construct Table Rows: Inside the loop, construct the table rows (<tr>) by appending the required HTML tags and values from each object in the sorted array.


Here's a simplified example using expressions and actions in Azure Logic Apps:

Sort Array:

Action: Sort array
Input: Your_JSON_Array
Order By: OrderId
Order: Ascending


Initialize HTML Table:

Action: Initialize variable
Name: HTML_Table
Type: String
Value: <table><thead><tr><th>OrderId</th><th>ProductId</th></tr></thead><tbody>


For Each:

Action: For each
Select the sorted array from the previous step as the input.
Inside the loop, append to the HTML_Table variable:

Action: Append to string variable
Name: HTML_Table
Value: <tr><td>@{items('For_each')?['OrderId']}</td><td>@{items('For_each')?['ProductId']}</td></tr>





Important: Since Foreach loops in Logic Apps and Power Platform, by default, trigger concurrently, this can cause reordering as some iterations may complete before others, and out of order. We need to control this behaviour, and force loop iterations to execute sequentially. This can be done by setting Concurrency 1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops?tabs=consumption#for-each-run-sequentially

Close HTML Table:

Action: Append to string variable
Name: HTML_Table
Value: </tbody></table>




I used the same process in my azure logic app but after close HTML Table action the product values are being inserted randomly not in ascending order.
But one thing there is no "Data Operations - Sort array" action available in the current Azure Logic App. The Data Operations section only includes actions such as Parse JSON, Create CSV Table, Create HTML Table, Select, Filter Array, Join, and Compose. Sort array action available in Power Assist not in Data Operations. I have some restrictions not to use third party connections.

Sort array action should be there in the portal. If you definitely can't see it, insert a compose action instead. In the expression, type sort(). Then inside the parentheses/brackets, switch to dynamic content tab and select the JSON output of the stored proc. Then for the second argument, specify ProductId. It should look something like this sort(body('storedproc', 'ProductId')

I have tried what you suggested, but I am not getting the desired result. Up to Foreach action, which includes the "Append to string" action, I am getting the sort order. However, after the "Close HTML Table" action, the product values are being inserted randomly instead of in ascending order.

@ChinnaSwamulu can you edit your question and include either screenshots of your workflow and action parameters, or an ARM template Template->Export Template?

@Jamie "Due to certain reasons, I am unable to share the ARM Template and Workflow. The main issue I am facing is that the values are being inserted in ascending order up to the 'foreach' loop, which includes appending to string variables. However, after the 'Close HTML Table' action, the product values are being inserted randomly instead of in ascending order. Could you please look into this?"

@ChinnaSwamulu OK, understandable. Sometimes people strip sensitive information and will share to allow others to reproduce the issue to dig deeper in to root cause. I found that a Foreach loop will actually run with parallelism, which is why some iterations may complete before others and cause reordering. Try this step to set concurrency to 1.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops?tabs=consumption#for-each-run-sequentially If this works I will update my answer.

I am grateful for your assistance, Jamie. You have provided me with a resolution to my issue.
